# Android device models to actual names

Tags: android

I want a mapping of model name such as SM-G950F to actual human name, i found a list here posted which is outdated, is there a up to date list?

I would also like to find screen sizes per model wise, if possible. Which is scaled down.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is a comprehensive and up-to-date list from google which includes all devices compatible to the Google Play Store:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, I did find this list, but it doesn't have the mapping of the names

Comment: You need to look at the header:
Retail Branding,Marketing Name,Device,Model

So for your example it would be:
Branding: Samsung,
Marketing Name: Galaxy S8,
Device: dreamlte,
Model: SM-G950F

Sure, some manufacturers have weird naming, but for most Branding + Marketing Name should be what you are looking for.